# Directus field type settings

Tags: directus

I'm trying to change a field type from Directus: the Dropdown.
Now it is set to a string and have [this interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsnaU.png), it is clear but not adapted if you want to enter more than 50 things in this field.

I saw that checkboxes' field type have [this interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBMZL.png), but i don't know how to swap dropdown interface to array interface that checkboxes have.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the "Repeater" interface is useful for short lists of items, but the UI isn't ideal for longer lists. There is an "accepted" Feature Request on GitHub to implement a raw JSON toggle option so that longer sets of data can be entered more quickly:

https://github.com/directus/app/issues/2083